# XHR request to simply execute CGI, without form

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I'm still trying to wrap my head around XHR requests.  Right now I currently have a CGI script that executes Python that updates a CSV file.

What I want to do is make an XHR request to call my CGI script.  I found a sample that successfully works, but at the moment it's only working on a button-click.  Here's a small snip:

```
    self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
    self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
```

It's all fine and I execute the CGI once I make a call to the XHR like so:

```
<form name="f1">
  <p>word: <input name="word" type="text">  
  <input value="Go" type="button" onclick='JavaScript:xmlhttpPost("/cgi-bin/myCGI.cgi")'></p>
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
```

This is probably a stupid question but how do I do this without having to click a button?  Does this have anything to do with the Content-Type?  From what I've read I should be using application/x-www-form-urlencoded, but the issue is I don't want to use any sort of form of any sort.. I simply want to make an XHR call to execute my CGI script without the use of a form.  I've noticed when I delete the form the script won't execute at all and I'm wondering what in my code is preventing this.

Comment: When do you want the XHR to be sent? You need some way of triggering it. If you want it to be sent every n milliseconds, use `setInterval(function (...) {...}, n)`, where n is the interval, in milliseconds, to execute the function.

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: When you call [`open` on an XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open()), you specify the method with the first parameter.  What you probably want is a GET request, not a POST request.

Comment: I need to call it at a specific point in my code.  Basically what I am trying to do is animate a line chart.  The way my data is now it doesn't maintain state, so my line chart is rendered from the CSV.  I shift the points in my CSV (this is what my CGI script does), and then I need to re-render, and repeat.  So I need to make the XHR request after each rendering of the graph, at that point in time.. if that makes sense.  I really suck at explaining things clearly..